# Dockerfile maven value

Tags: docker, maven, docker-compose, dockerfile

Which would be the correct value for this if I have an springboot app running on jdk 15? or where can I find the correct value for it?

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11 AS builder
```

I tried 3.6.3-jdk-15 but of course that was a guess and it did not work, is there a source from where I can get this?. (trying to use maven for building the image)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the exact version of maven you want at DockerHub and tab Tag

https://hub.docker.com/_/maven?tab=tags&page=1&ordering=last_updated.